# How to include extra files while creating a jar which are outside the source directory?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an extra directory that is present outside the src directory. Thus, when I am creating a jar it only includes the src directory. The application is running on my IDE but I need to run it through the jar and when I am creating a jar it does not include that folder. please help me how can I add this extra folder when I am creating a jar???

Comment: Which build tool you are using to create JAR?

Comment: I am using maven.